# buzzquiz - radio buttons aren't return anything

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create the whole quiz in JS (and I have to use different type of input all the time), I used eventListener to check the status of the button, but with the radio input it doesn't work. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>BuzzQuiz</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <!-- <link rel = "stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  </head>
    <body>
      <!-- HEADER -->
      <!-- START -->
      <div>
        <img id = "startImg" src = "http://img3.rnkr-static.com/list_img_v2/17520/2317520/C480/rick-and-morty-memes-that-all-fans-will-laugh-at.jpg">
        <input type = "submit" id = "startBtn" value = "I am ready!"></input>
      </div>
      <!-- CONTINUE -->
      <script src="js/foo.js"></script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

JS:

```
// are you ready?
document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener("click",
 (e) => {
 document.getElementById("startImg").src = "http://cdn3.thr.com/sites/default/files/2015/07/rick_and_morty_s02_still.jpg";
});

//change text to continue click

document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener("click",
(e) => {
var elem = document.getElementById("startBtn");
  if (elem.value=="I am ready!") {
      elem.value = "Continue";
  } else {
    var rmvbtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
    rmvbtn.remove();
    var rmvimg = document.getElementById("startImg");
    rmvimg.remove();
          var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
          var newStyle = document.createElement("H1");
          var firstQuestion = document.createTextNode("What is your name?");
          newStyle.appendChild(firstQuestion);
          newStyle.setAttribute("id", "question");
          var username = document.createElement("INPUT");
          username.setAttribute("type", "text");
          username.setAttribute("id", "userName");
          var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
          btn.setAttribute("id", "submitName");
          var btnText = document.createTextNode("Submit");
          btn.appendChild(btnText);
          var newPic = document.createElement("IMG");
          newPic.setAttribute("id","firstQuePic");
          newPic.setAttribute("src", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2d/bb/22/2dbb221505762fb32cfec3a21aa9749f.jpg");
                newDiv.appendChild(newStyle);
                newDiv.appendChild(newPic);
                username.appendChild(btn);
                newDiv.appendChild(username);
                newDiv.appendChild(btn);
                document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    document.getElementById("submitName").addEventListener("click",
  (e) => {
    var ifSubmit = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    if (ifSubmit.length!=-1) {
      console.log(ifSubmit);

      var rmvbtn = document.getElementById("submitName");
      rmvbtn.remove();
      var rmvform = document.getElementById("userName");
      rmvform.remove();
      var rmvheader = document.getElementById("question");
      rmvheader.remove();
      var rmvimg = document.getElementById("firstQuePic");
      rmvimg.remove();

              var newDivTwo = document.createElement("div");
              var newQueStyle = document.createElement("H1");
              var secQuestion = document.createTextNode("What is your gender?");
              newQueStyle.appendChild(secQuestion);
              newQueStyle.setAttribute("id", "question");

              var femDiv = document.createElement("div");
              var summerGen = document.createElement("IMG");
              summerGen.setAttribute("id","summerGender");
              summerGen.setAttribute("src", "http://www.aveleyman.com/Gallery/ActorsG/tve146453-3731-20131209-0.jpg");
              var fem = document.createElement("INPUT");
              fem.setAttribute("id", "female");
              fem.setAttribute("type", "radio");
              var ans1 = document.createTextNode("Female");
              femDiv.setAttribute("id","femaleDiv");
              femDiv.appendChild(summerGen);
              femDiv.appendChild(ans1);
              femDiv.appendChild(fem);

              var malDiv = document.createElement("div");
              var mortyGen = document.createElement("IMG");
              mortyGen.setAttribute("id","mortyGender");
              mortyGen.setAttribute("src","https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/710449830489890816/ef8uZJqk.jpg");
              var male = document.createElement("INPUT");
              male.setAttribute("id", "maLe");
              male.setAttribute("type", "radio");
              var ans2 = document.createTextNode("Male");
              malDiv.setAttribute("id","maleDiv");
              malDiv.appendChild(mortyGen);
              malDiv.appendChild(ans2);
              malDiv.appendChild(male);

              var hzDiv = document.createElement("div");
              var meeseksGen = document.createElement("IMG");
              meeseksGen.setAttribute("id", "msGen");
              meeseksGen.setAttribute("src", "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/647129820745199616/Yh4fqebK.png");
              var hz = document.createElement("INPUT");
              hz.setAttribute("id", "hZ");
              hz.setAttribute("type", "radio");
              var ans3 = document.createTextNode("I don't know");
              hzDiv.setAttribute("id","hezeDiv");
              hzDiv.appendChild(meeseksGen);
              hzDiv.appendChild(ans3);
              hzDiv.appendChild(hz);

              document.body.appendChild(newDivTwo);
              newDivTwo.appendChild(newQueStyle);
              newDivTwo.appendChild(femDiv);
              newDivTwo.appendChild(malDiv);
              newDivTwo.appendChild(hzDiv);

              var femAns = document.getElementById("female");
              var maleAns = document.getElementById("maLe");
              var hzAns = document.getElementById("hZ");

              if (femAns.checked) {
              alert("FEMALE");
              } else if (maleAns.checked) {
              alert("male")
              };



      }; //gender stuff appears
  }); //eventListener for gender


}

}); //eventListener for first click
```

I tried to debug it, variable assigns to the radiobutton id, but alert (as a test) doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Weird,I tried debugging the code,adding a true condition with the checkbox makes it appear onclick of the submit name button.Must have something to do with misplacing of the divs or setattibute.Hope this helps you debug it further.

```
 if (femAns.checked="true") {
              alert("FEMALE");
              } else if (maleAns.checked) {
              alert("male")
              };
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb1x344f/)